# Move pictures from one Facebook album to another

Tags: facebook, album

I have some pictures in my profile folder on Facebook that I want to move to another album. I don't want to lose the comments posted for each of those pictures.

Is this possible to move these across without losing the information and comments?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a possibility to do that yet.
Facebook is not exactly flickr yet.

Comment: not true, see @benregn's answer...

Comment: I was not wrong. It's not possible to do that for profile pictures because the source of profile pictures is from many albums and is auto generated. I know it's possible to edit albums in general but not the profile album specifically.

Therefore I repeat, it's not possible yet.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, just **not** for **Profile Picture** folder or any other **auto generated** albums. The Facebook Help page [How can I move photos between albums?](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=19135) contains a step by step guide:

```
1. Go to the full album view of an existing album.
2. Select "Edit Album Info" on the bottom left of the page.
3. Select the "Edit Photos" tab.
4. Select a destination album from the drop-down menu under 
each photo you wish to move.
5. Click "Save Changes."
```

There is also a Facebook app, [Fotolink](http://apps.facebook.com/fotolink).

"*Fotolink helps you to upload and download photos using drag and drop from facebook to your computer or to any online photo service.*"

I haven't used Fotolink but I read that when moving pictures comments and likes might not move with the pictures.

Comment: That does not work for the Profile Pictures Album. The point was not to lose the comments posted.

Comment: I dont see an "edit album info" on bottom of page